# Is there a way to automate the entire flow of creating a docker image of Bitbucket repo and then pushing it on AWS ECR?

Tags: python, docker, bitbucket-pipelines, amazon-ecr, aws-batch

I'm trying to create a docker image of Bitbucket repo and then push it on AWS ECR so that they can be used by AWS Batch to run various jobs.

So my basic requirement is to migrate my current jobs in Quartz to AWS batch, I need it to be automated such that when I push something in Bitbucket, its docker image should be created and added into the ECR to which then gets processed by AWS batch.

Any suggestions if it is right approach or can I use something else as well?

I tried pushing the docker image through bitbucket pipeline to AWS ECR.

Comment: What have you actually tried so far? Did you have any problem with that? Isn't it as simple as automating the `docker login; docker build; docker push` instructions? Could you share the relevant parts for your bitbucket-pipelines.yml file? Your actual question is unclear.

Comment: To the question "Is there a way to automate the entire flow of creating a docker image of Bitbucket repo and then pushing it on AWS ECR?" the answer is "Yes, there are plenty of totally valid ways to do that". Do you have any particular concern for the way you designed the automation?